# Laravel 5.4 and Gridstack.js

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-5.4, gridstack

How do I add a third party js file to specific blade views?

Basically I want to add gridstack functionality in a dashboard page inside my new project.

I already tried downloading the js and css files from [gridstack](/questions/tagged/gridstack), I then placed the gridstack.js in the project's `resources/assets/js/` folder, and the css files inside the project's `resources/assets/css/` folder

The next step would be to load the files in the mixer. For that I thought that I could just go to `/resources/assets/js/app.js` and add the library

```
require("./bootstrap");
//Add the following two lines
require("./jquery-ui.min");
require("./gridstack");
```

then I ran npm run dev, which gave the following errors

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 20 errors
>
> These dependencies were not found:
>
> jquery-ui/data in ./resources/assets/js/gridstack.js
>    jquery-ui/disable-selection in ./resources/assets/js/gridstack.js
>    *omitted 18 similar lines*
>
> To install them, you can run: npm install --save jquery-ui/data
>   jquery-ui/disable-selection jquery-ui/focusable jquery-ui/form
>   jquery-ui/ie jquery-ui/keycode jquery-ui/labels jquery-ui/jquery-1-7
>   jquery-ui/plugin jquery-ui/safe-blur jquery-ui/scroll-parent
>   jquery-ui/tabbable jquery-ui/unique-id jquery-ui/version
>   jquery-ui/widget jquery-ui/safe-active-element jquery-ui/widgets/mouse
>   jquery-ui/widgets/draggable jquery-ui/widgets/droppable
>   jquery-ui/widgets/resizable

Of course I tried to run `npm install --save jquery-ui/data` to see if it works and it does not:

> npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

**How can I add a simple js and css to my project without all these compilation errors...?**

I also tried another approach: removed the requires from the above approach, and went for the webpack.mix.js file and made it look like this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/app-landing.js', 'public/js/app-landing.js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/gridstack.js', 'public/js')
....
```

I then ran the `npm run dev` only to get the same error from above.

What is wrong here?
I tried to remove the jquery-ui refference and run the npm again... the exact same error

Also, I installed gridstack using npm in my project... but I have no idea how to directly use it. I should be able to use it, since it is "installed", but how?

I also did a `npm cache clean`, no effect
I also verified my versions of node and npm, they seem ok:

```
node v6.10.3
npm  v3.10.10
```

**EDIT**
After removing the ./ from the require, and after removing the jquery-ui altogether (it was already loaded) I managed to get no more errors from the npm command.
However the gridstack functionality is just not there. I compared my sources with an [official demo](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/float.html) of gridstack and saw that they include 2 js files of gridstack:

```
<script src="../dist/gridstack.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/gridstack.jQueryUI.js"></script>
```

But Laravel mix does not agree with me adding the extra require. I get errors again from npm if in /resources/assets/js/app.js I put the following

```
require("./bootstrap");
require("gridstack");
require("gridstack.jQueryUI"); // nor does it work if I use gridstack.all.js or gridstack.jQueryUI.js
```

What can I do to get the gridstack full functionality inside my Laravel 5.4 project?

**EDIT**
What seemed to work is:

1. remove all changes done previously like the one in app.js
2. I copied webpack.config.js from node_modules/laravel-mix into my project's root folder
3. I added the bellow code

   module.exports.resolve = {
       extensions,
       alias: {
           'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
           'jquery-ui': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery-ui/ui')
       }
   };
4. In webpack.mix.js, I added the following:

   mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .copy('node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.all.js','public/js');
5. in package.json I added:

   "devDependencies": {
       ...
       "gridstack": "^0.3.0"
     }
6. in the command line I did

   sudo npm rebuild node-sass

then

```
sudo npm run dev
```

After I the above, npm compiles correctly the mix, bun now, I get a jQuery error in the frontend:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: c.draggable is not a function
>   d.prototype.draggable@http://myproject.com/js/gridstack.all.js:16:1395

This points to the second part of the gridstack.all.js (right at the beginning of it, where jquery is defined... again)
Error seems to indicate that jquery is loaded more than once. But that is not a problem in a classic PHP app.

Any idea how to make this work?
The default laravel application requires by default Bootstrap, lodash and jquery, and when I add gridstack to the project, looks like somewhere there is a second require for jquery. I just don't get it.

> Can anyone try to simulate what I am doing and tell me how they did
>   it?

Comment: Just curious.... what is the downvote for?

Comment: Your question seems to be a large wall of text, if I quickly read the question I cannot see a clear question, it looks to be a "how do I fix this problem" kind of question which lacks a  MVCE.

Comment: Could you try the require statements without prepending them with `./` thus using `require('gridstack')`

Comment: I already did that, and it worked, however, Laravel does not seem to like/interpret gridstack.js if I do this. It has no more errors when I run npm run dev, but the functionality is just not there. I did a test outside Laravel and it is the same. It needs the other js file too.It needs the gridstack.jQueryUI.js which is included in gridstack.all.js. So how can I add gridstack.all.js or gridstack.jQueryUI.js to my project so that it would have the functionality? It does not work like using gridstack.js does

Comment: Sorry, the question is a wall of text because I like to be explicit, and also it contains a large error message... I could not exclude that. It is hard to make this a MVCE, but I can tell you that the following demo works : http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/float.html but I cannot get to test it because the Laravel Mix does not compile with those JS requirements. I was hoping for someone that added third party JS files before, like gridstack to their project

Comment: For those interested, I managed to advance with my problem only to meet another. So far what I did can be fount in the latest EDIT of the question. I will post there the current problem too

Answer (score 0):

you need to include gridstack via asset() then everything will be happy - for this example the files are in /public/js/dashboard
eg (the hootsuite grid demo page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Grid Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard/style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/dashboard/fixtures.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/dashboard/gridList.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/dashboard/jquery.gridList.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/dashboard/load.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="#remove-row" class="button remove-row">-</a>
    <a href="#add-row" class="button add-row">+</a>
    <p>
      <a class="github-button" href="https://github.com/hootsuite/grid" data-style="mega" data-count-href="/hootsuite/grid/stargazers" data-count-api="/repos/hootsuite/grid#stargazers_count" data-count-aria-label="# stargazers on GitHub" aria-label="Star hootsuite/grid on GitHub">GitHub</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <ul id="grid" class="grid">
      <li class="position-highlight">
        <div class="inner"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script async defer id="github-bjs" src="https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```